# Setting locale with DefaultHttpClient?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I'm using DefaultHttpClient to make an http connection. I [think] we can set the preferred locale in the http headers [http accept-language] when making a connection, which the server can check and send back content in a matching language (if it wants).

Anyone know if this is possible, or how to go about doing this with DefaultHttpClient?

Thanks

Comment: DefaultHttpClient? - to which package/lib does it belong?

Comment: @Ralph: as per OP's question history, it's likely Android.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add your header to `HttpRequest` object

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```